# SSIS Script Task Special Characters

Tags: ssis

I am trying to get some data from an API, using an SSIS Script Task with Visual Basic code. But I having some problems because I have Portuguese special characters in some fields. I was trying to solve my problems and I read that this could be achieved by enconding the data. I try to do this with any sucess.

Can anyone help me?

Regards

```
Using c As WebClient = New WebClient()
            c.BaseAddress = URL
            c.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization) = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key & ":" & pass))
            c.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(key, pass)
            Dim xml = c.DownloadString(URL & "CRUser?start=0&count=999&language=English")

            'Parse para objetos
            Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(xml)

            Dim reader = doc.CreateReader()

            Dim xRoot As XmlRootAttribute = New XmlRootAttribute()
            xRoot.ElementName = "array"
            xRoot.IsNullable = True

            Dim xmls As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of CRUser)), xRoot)
            Dim _data As List(Of CRUser) = xmls.Deserialize(reader)
            For Each item As CRUser In _data
                'Console.WriteLine(item.id)
                'Console.WriteLine(item.firstName)
                '..... resto campos injetar no pipelino do SSIS os dados
                MyOutputBuffer.AddRow()
                MyOutputBuffer.id = item.id
                MyOutputBuffer.firstName = item.firstName

            Next
        End Using
```

Comment: What's the actual error do you get with this code?

Comment: The code is correct but the data is not. For instance if a person calls João it apears Jo%&o.